# xcode graph scene not visible

Tags: ios, scenekit, xcode7.2

2 in yosemite vmware 10.10 my problem is that whenever I create a game project and click on **art.scnassets** and select **ship.scn** file to open in scene view the ship model not shown visible in xcode scene graph. it just empty screen. Also if I drag a 3D sphere and floor from toolbar it also not appear in xcode scene graph I am attaching the image please help me how can I see my 3d model scene graph for aditing properties and textures..

[image]

Comment: I have same problem, could you find any solution???

Comment: Scene Graph is completely blank, even after adding a default box, But when running the app the box mesh shows in the view. Is xcode's 3d viewport broken? Is there another way to edit .scn?

Answer (score 2):

You can work around this issue by making a copy of the .scn file at the file level on your mac. Make sure you make the copy within the art.scnassets folder.

This copy should have all toolbars and controls associated with it. Once you have verified this you can delete the original and rename the copy.

Answer (score 2):

It's sneaky. Click this button on the bottom-left corner and it will launch a Scene Graph interface that you can click and edit things on.

[image: From RayWenderlich]

Comment: This is NOT Xcode 7.2

Comment: There was no version specified in the question

Comment: Yes, check the **tag**.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the toolbar item that currently reads "No Selection". Or click on the name of the scene ("ship.scn") to see child nodes.

[image]